# Apache Kafka dropping my Producers and Consumers

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a major unpredictable issue with Apache Kafka. I am using Kafka 0.8 and after couple hours of running it starts dropping my applications. Specially the producer.

The behaviour is unpredictable and I cannot consistently reproduce it.

- My OS is Mac OS
- I am using Java 7 (Producer is a web application)
- I am running two topics and two servers on the same box on 9092 and 9093

I see the following errors on the Zookeeper

```
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x14d1b94a22d001b, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-05-03 20:35:37,988] INFO Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60236 which had sessionid 0x14d1b94a22d001b (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2015-05-03 20:35:37,989] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:60204 which had sessionid 0x14d1b94a22d0016 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2015-05-03 20:35:37,989] WARN Ignoring unexpected runtime exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.readyOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:87)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:187)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And here is the error I see on the 9093 server

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Kafka scheduler has not been started
    at kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler.ensureStarted(KafkaScheduler.scala:114)
    at kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler.shutdown(KafkaScheduler.scala:86)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerResignation(KafkaController.scala:350)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener$$anonfun$handleNewSession$1.apply$mcZ$sp(KafkaController.scala:1108)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener$$anonfun$handleNewSession$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:1107)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener$$anonfun$handleNewSession$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:1107)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:535)
    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$SessionExpirationListener.handleNewSession(KafkaController.scala:1107)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient$4.run(ZkClient.java:472)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread.run(ZkEventThread.java:71)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The logs suggest that zookeeper is temporarily disconnecting, increase the zookeeper time out value